# Cannot run libpd app

Tags: ios, puredata

I'm new to libpd. I downloaded the pd-for-ios and installed as required. Then opened up a sample xcode project in the folder, and successfully compiled the project.

Then When I try to run the app on either my iPad or on Simulators, it won't run. Each time I hit the "play" button in my xcode, it just says "build succeed" and then nothing happens.

I have tried the DispatcherSample project and WaveTable project, and the same thing happens. Just to verify, I opened up another non-libpd ios app project and it can compile and run on either simulator or my iPad.

Where might have gone wrong? IOS v6.0.1, Xcode V4.5, Mac OS 10.7.5

Thanks!

Weibin

Comment: Set the scheme in the top left to something other than libpd.  Frameworks are not system-executable applications, so nothing should run.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I figured that out later yesterday, but thank you  all the same.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the build scheme wasn't correctly selected. The default was "libpd-ios", when I switch it to what is same as the project name, it runs.